# Is there a solution for ios bing maps sdk for armv7s? Or should use bing ajax control v7 into a UIWebview?

Tags: ios, bing-maps, iphone-5

Is there a solution for ios bing maps sdk for arm7vs? Or should use bing ajax control v7 into a UIWebview?

I am working in this app that needs bing and got an error saying that the static library of bing is not for armv7s. I know I can remove support for armv7s by removing it in the valid architecture but I really need to have the app running in iPhone 5. Any recommendations or solutions guys?

Comment: It will still run on the iPhone 5 without armv7s, it just wont have the optimizations of armv7s (I think there's improvement to floating point arithmetic and some other things, but nothing you need to care about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all I found out that it is working for iPhone 5 but it's performance is a bit shaky. I will add some more information if I have optimized the usage of bing maps ios sdk in iPhone 5.

Comment: @bjectiveCarlo how you make that to work in iPhone 5 ?

Comment: @MoorthyTheBoss sorry for the late reply this was last year I'm not sure if the solution will still work. Basically I just remove the armv7s in the valid architecture settings. Though there were other problems like random crashing and stuff so I recommend that you move on to another map library.

Answer (score 0):

> I can remove support for armv7s by removing it in the valid architecture but I really need to have the running in iPhone 5.

ARM is generally a platform respecting backwards compatibility. If you compile for ARMv6, for example, all generations of iOS devices will be able to run the app (except if you use APIs that only available in newer versions of iOS).

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I am talking about forward compatibility.

Comment: @objectiveCarlo No. I said the same thing as MaxGabriel explained.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try out an other mapping library, then have a look at https://github.com/route-me/route-me It does have suppport for multiple mapping providers.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will use it for my next project.